# If $X \times \{0\} \cup A \times I$ is closed in $X \times I$. Then, is $A$ closed in $X$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space, $A$ subset of $X$.
Let $I$ be an interval $[0,1] \subset {\mathbb R}$.
Suppose that $X \times \{0\} \cup A \times I$ is closed in $X \times I$.
Then, is $A$ closed in $X$?

It seems that it is , 
since that is the explanation in *Algebraic Topology* by Allen Hatcher
of the claim:

> If $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property, then $A$ must be a closed subspace
>   of $X$, at least when $X$ is Hausdorff.

But, I don't understand why it is.

Comment: Yes. By taking complements ($B=X\setminus A$) it suffices to show: if $B\times(I\setminus\{0\})$ is open in $X\times I$, then $B$ is open in $X$. And this isn't hard to prove - by finding a neighborhood contained in $B$ of every point $x\in B$, using a neighborhood of $x\times\frac12$ say contained in $B\times(0,1]$.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that $B\times (0,1]$ is the complement of $X \times \{0\} \cup A \times I$ in $X \times I$. If it is true, then it follows that $B\times (0,1]$ is open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $Y=A\times I \cup X\times\{0\}$ is closed in $X\times I$, then $Y\cap (X\times\{1\})$ is closed in $X\times\{1\}$. But this set is just $A\times\{1\}$, and if $A\times\{1\}$ is closed in $X\times\{1\}$, then $A$ must be closed in $X$.